# Determine if the functions are differentiable at $x=4$

Tags: calculus, functions, continuity

analyze the function

$$f(x)= \begin{cases}\sqrt{4x}+11 & \text{if }x \ge 4 \\ \frac12 x+13 & \text{if }x < 4 \end{cases}$$

I am trying to determine if the equations are differentiable at $x=4$.
I know that I need to difference quotient of    $\frac{f(4+h)-f(4)}h$.
Where I am stuck is how to compute from here?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. When you wrote $\sqrt4x$, did you mean to write $\sqrt{4x}$?

Comment: Check the limit from either side of $x=4$. Use the function definition to work through the difference quotient; when $x\to4$ from below, $x<4$ so $f(x)=\frac12x+13$; while from above, $x>4$ so $f(x)=\sqrt{4x}+11$.

Comment: Left and right derivatives are the same at 4?

Comment: Maybe I didn't ask the right question, if I compute f(4) into the equations, both come out equal to 15. This means that they are continuous. I guess what I am not understanding is the difference of quotient formula, what value goes in for h and how to solve from there?

Comment: @RickSanders If $h>0$, plug in the function for $x \ge 4$. If $h < 0$, plug in the function for $x < 4$. For $f$ to be differentiable, the limits for both $h>0$ and $h<0$ must exist and agree with each other.

Comment: Both functions $g(x)=2\sqrt{x}+11$ and $h(x)={1\over 2}x+13$ are differentiable at $x=4$ and   $g(4)=h(4).$  Thus $f'_-(4)=g'(4)={1\over 2}$ and $f'_+(4)=h'(4).={1\over 2}.$ In this way you avoid calculating  limits.

Answer (score 1):

$f(x)$ is differentiable at $x=4$ if the limit

$$\lim_{x\to4} \frac{f(x) - f(4)}{x - 4} \stackrel{h=x-4}= \lim_{h\to0} \frac{f(4+h) - f(4)}h$$

exists and is finite.

- If $x<4$, then $f(x) = \frac x2+13$ and

$$\lim_{x\to4} \frac{\frac x2+13 - 15}{x - 4} = \lim_{x\to4} \frac{\frac x2 - 2}{x-4} = \frac12 \lim_{x\to4} \frac{x-4}{x-4} = \frac12$$

- Otherwise, if $x>4$, then $f(x)=\sqrt{4x}+11$ and

$$\lim_{x\to4} \frac{\sqrt{4x}+11 - 15}{x - 4} = \lim_{x\to4} \frac{\sqrt{4x} - 4}{x-4} = 2 \lim_{x\to4} \frac{\sqrt x - 2}{\left(\sqrt x-2\right)\left(\sqrt x+2\right)} = \frac12$$

The one-sided limits agree, so the two-sided limit exists and $f$ is indeed differentiable at $x=4$.

If you wish to consider the $h$-limit instead, the only practical difference is considering whether $h<0$ or $h>0$. But $h=x-4$, so $x<4\implies h<0$ and $x>4\implies h>0$ respectively so you end up with the same conclusion.

Comment: Thanks to all!. Thanks @user170231 , I needed the visual to understand what was actually going on here!